# Prevent using wildcard in Apache server alias setting

Tags: apache-2.2

This is a modified VirtualHost setting from my server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /mnt/example/public


  <Directory /mnt/example/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I found that I can access the example.com and also *.example.com, e.g. www.example.com, abcde.example.com, etc.

I know there should be a ServerAlias setting which let me activate wildcard subdomain suppot. But I can't see the ServerAlias setting my VirtualHost or Apache config file.

I want to allow only www.example.com and example.com can access my site, and other subdomain will get a 404 error.

How can I set this up?

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're missing before all your vhost containers in the conf file is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Once you've done that, depending on what you want to do for all those wildcards you deem "invalid" you can create the required `<virtualhost>` containers, and then followup with a final one with a wildcard that acts a catchall for the rest.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

For instance, what I've done is have a vhost container for myhost.mydomain.tld, and then whatever other domains, and finally, I have a container for *.mydomain.tld that basically points to a static page notifying people to mind their own business.

Comment: Thanks. After I added NameVirtualHost *:80, the apache give me a warning when I restart it. "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts". But your last solution is great, I will just create a static page for that. Thanks :)